# Is there a way to map an array of objects in Go?

Tags: go, generics, higher-order-functions

Coming from Node.js, I could do something like:

```js
// given an array `list` of objects with a field `fruit`:

fruits = list.map(el => el.fruit) # which will return an array of fruit strings
```

Any way to do that in an elegant one-liner in Go?

I know I can do it with a range loop, but I am looking for the possibility of a one-liner solution.

Comment: Give it a minute. With 1.18 (released literally last week) it finally becomes possible to write this as a function. In another year or two it might even make it into the stdlib :)

Comment: @hobbs do you have an example by any chance? Or a link to documentation? I can't find anything

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In Go, arrays used as function parameters are inflexible (because their length is encoded in their type) and costly (because a function operates on copies of its array arguments). I'm assuming you'd like to operate on [*slices*](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Slice_types) rather than on arrays.

Because [methods cannot take additional type arguments](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md#methods-may-not-take-additional-type-arguments), you cannot simply declare a generic `Map` *method* in Go. However, you can define `Map` as a generic *top-level function*:

```golang
func Map[T, U any](ts []T, f func(T) U) []U {
    us := make([]U, len(ts))
    for i := range ts {
        us[i] = f(ts[i])
    }
    return us
}
```

Then you can write the following code,

```golang
names := []string{"Alice", "Bob", "Carol"}
fmt.Println(Map(names, utf8.RuneCountInString))
```

which prints `[5 3 5]` to stdout (try it out in [this Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/JsFvX50sbQc)).

---

Go 1.18 saw the addition of [a `golang.org/x/exp/slices` package](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slices), which provides many convenient operations on slices, but a `Map` function is noticeably absent from it. The omission of that function was the result of a long discussion in the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45955) dedicated to the `golang.org/x/exp/slices` proposal; concerns included the following:

- [hidden cost (O(n)) of operations behind a one-liner](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45955#issuecomment-832905988)
- [uncertainty about error handling inside `Map`](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45955#issuecomment-832913077)
- [risk of encouraging a style that strays too far from Go's traditional style](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45955#issuecomment-833154112)

Russ Cox [ultimately](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/45955#issuecomment-884406307) elected to drop `Map` from the proposal because it's

> probably better as part of a more comprehensive streams API somewhere else.

[The `slices` package](https://pkg.go.dev/slices) (added in Go 1.21) doesn't provide any `Map` function either.

Comment: The argument about Map “hide de costs” seems weird if we think about `strings.Split` - in fact the discussion is longer and I did not follow it completely. Must check

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj True. That GitHub issue is quite long (300+ comments). I'm working my way through it. I'll report here when I've read it all.

Comment: I read something about covariance. I need a coffe to read it all. Thanks

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj Hypothetical `Map`, `Filter` & `Reduce` functions can be chained, each incurring a cost of O(n). Contrast that to `strings.Split`, which cannot easily be chained with other functions, in part because Go has no tuples.

Comment: It's a valid point and a big difference between the Java Streams API and the JS functions. In JS A.map().filter().map().reduce() will iterate the array 4 times and create 3 intermediate array structures. Regarding performance and memory consumption this is quite inefficient (even more so in go if it operates on structs which are possibly copied multiple times) - and a language like Go would probably favor something like Java lazy streams, which will only collect items on final functions..

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what you are referring to the word "Map". In golang [map](https://go.dev/blog/maps) is something like dictionary where you have key and value `map[key]value`.

Bellow is a helper function (must go to [maps](https://golang.org/x/exp/maps) package) which allows to create a map in go:

```golang
func Map[T, K comparable, V any](arr []T, f_key func(T) K, f_val func(T) V) map[K]V {
    m := make(map[K]V, len(arr))
    for i := range arr {
        m[f_key(arr[i])] = f_val(arr[i])
    }
    return m
}

// Usage
var m = Map(books, 
    func(b Book) string { return b.Id }, 
    func(b Book) Book { return b }
)
```

Please see playground: https://go.dev/play/p/Bak3gfY0UV0

The `map` in nodejs is a function which allows to go through elements and build your own type in *one line. In this case please see @jub0bs answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71624929/1143349